# wget saving files as emply plain text files on boot

Tags: shell-script, cron, wget, init-script, reboot

I have a bash script in crontab that runs @reboot:

The script itself contains a wget command to pull and download a file from the internet

When I run my script after signing in and opening the terminal it works and saves the files properly(html, png). But when I reboot my system it saves runs and saves as plain text files with no content.

---

### Solved

--> I used the sleep function in crontab and it works!!!

New to linux and code, so thanks for all the feedback! I'm going to explore the /etc/network/if-up.d/ options as well.

Comment: When your script runs, is the network accessible yet?

Comment: Please post the entry from `crontab` as well as some portion of the script so we can assist further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is [almost](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/almost) certainly that your `@reboot` cron job has started before your network interfaces have come `up`. [This is, in general, a well-documented shortcoming of `cron`.](https://www.unixdaemon.net/linux/how-does-cron-reboot-work/) It doesn't mean the `@reboot` facility is useless, it just means you need to understand how it works, and how to work around it when it fails - as it has in your case ([probably](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/probably) :).

There are at least 2 ways to do this:

1. use `sleep` in your @reboot job to give the network more time to get `up`. Your `crontab` entry will look something like this: :

> @reboot sleep 10; /your/bash/script/as-it-is-now

I suggested the value of `10` here to give the interface 10 seconds to come `up`; YMMV, so experiment with different values.

2. following up on @confetti 's suggestion (and with thanks to @Celada), put your script in `/etc/network/if-up.d`. Following is a prototype that may be useful. Note that it only runs the first time your system comes up (like `@reboot`, and NOT each time the network interface is brought `up`):

> #!/bin/sh
>
> NWKSTATUS=/var/run/the-network-is-up
>
> # note that /var/run is a temp fs, and so a system shutdown
>   # will effectively erase our flag file, 'the-network-is-up'
>
> case "$IFACE" in
>       lo)
>           # Exclude the loopback interface; we won't consider it
>           # as it's not a true interface. We set the flag only
>           #  when a true network interface comes up
>           exit 0
>           ;;
>       *)
>           ;;
>   esac
>
> # if the flag file exists, we're done here
>   # otherwise, we'll create it
>
> if [ -e $NWKSTATUS ]; then
>       exit 0
>   else
>       touch $NWKSTATUS
>   fi
>
> # add your script here...

So - put all of the above into a file (e.g. `setnwkstatus.sh`), then save it in the folder `/etc/network/if-up.d/` and make it executable (i.e. `sudo chmod /etc/network/if-up.d/setnwkstatus.sh` )

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue is that the network interface isn't up at the time `cron` tries to run your script.

You could make the script run after the network interface is up.

Put your script in `/etc/network/if-up.d` and set `chmod +x` so it can be executed. Everytime a network interface comes up, every script in there will be executed.