# Python file fail on a crontab job

Tags: cron

I'm using RPI zerow to run a python code (Raspbian Strech-Lite).

I need to run 2 file during startup: `MQTTlogger.py` and `Sched_MQTT.py`.
Both files run OK using command line, but when I added 2 job on `crontab` only one of them get executed ( the second file ). file name and path are OK.

Searching in all log files in `/var/log` did not show aany evidence for failure during boot.

Any idea why ?

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/guy/github/SmartHome_SoC/MQTTswitches/MQTTlogger.py
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/guy/github/SmartHome_SoC/MQTTswitches/Sched_MQTT.py
```

> EDIT1: running only `MQTTLOGGER.PY`

leaving only `MQTTlogger.py` in `crontab` shows that it is a problem with running in `crontab` rather than running one after the other.

what can be the reason for file fail to run on a `crontab` job, but succeed when executed on a command line ? how can I debug it ?

> EDIT2 : trying to catch crontab error

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/guy/github/SmartHome_SoC/MQTTswitches/MQTTlogger.py >> /home/guy/crontab.log 2>&1
```

yields :

```
File "/home/guy/github/SmartHome_SoC/MQTTswitches/MQTTlogger.py", line 1, in <module>
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
ImportError: No module named 'paho'
```

so I'm guessing it has something to do with path to the MQTT package

Comment: Does one have to run before the other? Cron will run them pretty much simultaneously.  Did you get any form of error mailed to you (or to the user whose crontab this is)? Do they depend on certain environment variables having certain values?

Comment: @Kusalananda - no, each one stands for itself. I did not find any error posted ( as said )

Comment: Answered in :[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232281/python-path-to-mqtt-paho-due-to-failure-in-crontab?noredirect=1#comment91413919_52232281)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue is that `cron` is trying to run these jobs (one or both) before a service has become available. The easy way to fix this is to add a `sleep` delay to wait for the required services to get started:

```
@reboot sleep 10; /usr/bin/python3 /home/guy/github/SmartHome_SoC/MQTTswitches/MQTTlogger.py && /usr/bin/python3 /home/guy/github/SmartHome_SoC/MQTTswitches/Sched_MQTT.py
```

Your issue is [similar to the one in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459735/wget-saving-files-as-emply-plain-text-files-on-boot/459895#459895), so you may wish to refer to it for additional information.

You may also want to redirect your `stderr` to a file to capture any output for debugging purposes. Do that by adding this to the and of the `crontab` line I've listed above:

`> ~/cronjoblog 2>&1`

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm changing my original question - since trying to run only `MQTTlogger.py` fails. so it has nothing to do with the fact of sleep period between - BUT can you explain more about `stderr` and how to redirect errors to a file

Comment: Did you try running with `sleep`?

Comment: Yes. See edit2- it was a path issue. 

Comment: So - all is well then... your script runs??

Comment: yes, by the way- since MQTT needs some time until network is UP, `sleep` was necessary!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, but still confused by your comment above: "It was a path issue". But nevertheless, if `sleep` was the answer, could you mark that as the accepted answer?

Comment: As you can see in edit 2- the reason it failed running was the need to define path for ‘crontab’ job. After fixing this - the code started running - some errors occurred regrading some fails reaching MQTT ( lack of network connection at this time ).

Comment: By the way - path definition was made inside python code ( it does not shown here)

Answer (score 0):

two things that solved my problem:

1 ) adding `sleep` to `crontab`- as Seamus suggested:

```
@reboot sleep 10; /usr/bin/python3 /home/guy/github/SmartHome_SoC/MQTTswitches/MQTTlogger.py >> /home/guy/crontab.log 2>&1`
```

2) fixing path inside code to fix path ( as asked in stackover flow ), [reffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52232281/python-path-to-mqtt-paho-due-to-failure-in-crontab?noredirect=1#comment91413919_52232281)